# How to get a table cell value in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, html-table, tampermonkey

I am **Chrome** user and I would like to **customize some website**. I have **Tampermonkey** (something similar to Greasemonkey for Firefox) extension for my Chrome. Now I can add some Javascript code for specific website.

Now, all I want is to get value from some table and show it in popup window.

Example of HTML code:

```
<div id="Content">

<table><tbody><tr>
<td>Text number 1</td>
<td>Text number 2</td>
</tr></tdoby></table>

<table><tbody><tr>
<td>Text number 3</td>
<td>Text number 4</td>
</tr></tdoby></table>

<table><tbody><tr>
<td>Text number 5</td>
<td>Text number 6</td>
</tr></tdoby></table>

</div>
```

My code so far:

```
var xpath = "id('Content')/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]";
var result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
myWin=window.open('','','width=400,height=400');
myWin.document.write(result);
```

but it doesn't show content of this "td" (Text number 2)

any idea?

Comment: Where is `result` defined?

Comment: sorry I have missed code, check now

Comment: Is XPath necessary to you in this case? Or can you use something else? Remember that it does not work in IE!

Comment: Your XPath is no standard XPath. What is your input and expected output of this XPath?

Comment: i can use something else, all I want to do is to get text from table and show this text in popup window

Comment: Updated my answer with your HTML code(updated the JSFiddle too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created your HTML structure based on XPath you gave.
Since you don't need XPath, I would use normal element accessing:

**HTML**

```
<div id="Content">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text number 1</td>
                <td>Text number 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text number 3</td>
                <td>Text number 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Text number 5</td>
                <td>Text number 6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var div = document.getElementById('Content'),
    table = div.getElementsByTagName('table')[1],
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0],
    td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
alert(td.innerHTML);
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvHYw/2/)

Comment: what if I have table in table?

Comment: You have to change the JS code according to what you want to do. If you have the basics, you can do that without trouble. If you don't, it is a good idea to start from DOM Elements accessing

Comment: example: id('Content')/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td

Comment: Thank you. It is working good, I do very appreciate your help but is there any easier way to get this element ? like giving a full path of this element?

Comment: IMHO it is a crazy thing to have all those nested elements, anyway you can use `document.querySelector` using CSS selector to get your element. In this case it would be `document.querySelector("#Content table:nth-of-type(1) tr td:nth-of-type(1)")`

Comment: http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/751/selectors-api.html this is a good point to start with, then you have to learn how to access your elements. Notice that `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` don't take care of the older browsers. http://caniuse.com/queryselector this is `querySelector` compatibility

Answer (score 2):

That is not quite how you use XPath.  `result`, in this case is an [*iterator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Iterators).

The code would be something like:

```
var xpath   = "id('Content')/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]";
var result  = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var node    = result.iterateNext();
var nodeTxt = node.textContent
var myWin   = window.open('','','width=400,height=400');
myWin.document.write (nodeTxt);
```

except, **don't use XPath!**  Since you are starting out, use `document.querySelector` or, better yet, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Here's the [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) way:

```
var node    = document.querySelector (
    "#Content > table:first-child > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)"
);
var nodeTxt = node.textContent
alert (nodeTxt);
```

Note. use `alert()` or a jQuery UI dialog for this kind of thing.  Avoid trying to use `window.open` if you can help it.

Here's **a complete script**, showing the jQuery way:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var nodeTxt = $("#Content > table:first > tbody > tr > td:eq(1)").text ();
alert (nodeTxt);
```